# XLPagerTabStrip - How to add UISearchController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uisearchcontroller, xlpagertabstrip

I am using this library:  https://github.com/xmartlabs/XLPagerTabStrip

My problem is that I can't resolve an issue with adding a UISearchController for one of `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController` child viewController - `UITableViewController`.

The searchBar does not appear when trying to add it under iOS 11+ like this:

```
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
navigationItem.hidesSearchBarWhenScrolling = true
```

and when trying to add `UISearchBar` to `tableView` as this:

```
tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
```

then after tapping into the search field the whole `UISearchBar` disappears.

Do you know any proper way how to implement `UISearchController` in a `UITableViewController` with `ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController` as a one of childs?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an overdue answer but hopefully will help others who might have the same issue.

adding following properties to your searchbar fixes the issue:

```
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.definesPresentationContext = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in the container controller, the one that extends ButtonBarPagerTabStripViewController

```
definesPresentationContext = true
```

and  put this code in the Child View Controllers

```
definesPresentationContext = false
```